# How to enable Apache2 mods before starting apache from Docker

Tags: docker, apache2

I'm string to start a Docker container from image `FROM envoyproxy/envoy-dev:latest`. My `entrypoint` has a shell script:

```sh
exec a2enmod ssl &
exec a2enmod rewrite &
# exec apache2 start &
exec /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND &
envoy -c /etc/service-envoy.yaml --service-cluster some_cluster
```

None of the start command works. I have to access the container then execute commands for `a2enmod` then `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND` to start the server. Do you need any other information? That's the only issue I have so far.

Comment: Usually you’d run commands like `a2enmod` in a Dockerfile, and you’d run separate processes like Apache and the Envoy proxy in separate containers.

Comment: OMG! I've never thought of that! `RUN a2enmod ssl` works. Thanks